# Is there an Elastic Search Beat that can read from a Kafka Topic

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, kibana, heartbeat

I have an ELK setup with an output going directly to the Elastic Search rather than into Logstash. We are using ELK ver 7.3.2 with a Basic license and running under a Linux RedHat.

We have a topology of 3 Kafka Nodes and 2 Cassandra Nodes.
I was able to configure a metricbeat with a default setup. This metricbeat picks up Kafka groups and topic names coming though this VM host but it not enough to see if the consumers go down.

It was easy to configure a Heartbeat that will ping 3 Kafka nodes.

That is not enough for my team.

- Why a metricbeat picks up Kafka topics?
- Is there a Beat that I can install and configure to read directly from Kafka topic?
- Is there a way to setup metricbeat to read from Kafka and output into Elastic Search ?

Comment: Why not logstash? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html

Answer (score 1):

Metricbeat collects metrics not only on the system level, but also from services running on that system. 
Here is a [list](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-modules.html) of the metric collecting modules included in Metricbeat. 
The list covers many services and platforms including Kafka.

As for the question of how to read from a Kafka topic to Elasticsearch, the obvious ways are either using logstash or Kafka Connect. There is a supported confluent [connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html#elasticsearch-overview) for Elasticsearch.

There isn't a supported Beat to read directly from a Kafka topic. But after some research, I found one developed by [JustSocialLabs](https://github.com/justsocialapps/kafkabeat). I haven't tried it. My experience with using both Logstash and Kafka connect was suffecient. But you can give it a shot if you want.

Comment: Currently [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html#elasticsearch-overview) is not supported for 7.x
I will look into Kafka Connect more.